# Is there a downside to adding an entire block list to UFW

Tags: networking, proxy, http-proxy, nginx

I made a nginx based proxy server that redirects traffic for a few machines so they can have a single security filter that I can maintain. Nothing crazy, just enough to block a few ad tracking agencies and save a bit on my limited data plans.

Anyways, nginx was perfect in terms of performance and actually sped up a few of my devices while using the web. However, filtering solutions for nginx haven't been easy to come by so I've had to work with Ubuntu to see where else a filter could exist.

I added a few open source lists of malicious ip and anti-tracking lists to the hosts file and found that sometimes nginx would work right around the hosts file so that went right down the drain so I started looking at a firewall based solution.

While I know ufw wasn't designed to block domains, it was the only one that was successful at completely blocking nginx from requesting the undesired link so I threw together a shell script that has the ip of all of the listed domains along with recorded malicious IP addresses which my machine is now crunching through.

```
# Example of the script
ufw deny out to 1.2.3.4;
ufw deny out to 1.2.3.5;
ufw deny out to 1.2.3.6;
```

My question to you guys is since this is taking so long for the script to crunch through in my not very busy digitalocean droplet, will I notice a performance decreased since there will be so many IPtables rules? Or is UFW just a setup layer which has no influence on how IPtables runs and might possibly be a bit bulky considering that it's a UI focused app? I figure with how mature IP tables is, that's not going to suffer that much of an overhead and don't mind a one time wait but I am a little concerned only because of how long it's taking the script to load every rule into the rules.

I suppose I could have just had this piped into one of the config files but I felt as though running it through the easy to use command interphase was the stable and safe solution. What do you guys think?